# server rewrite on serializaation to GWT, but hibernate on server

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, serialization

Well basically i have a shared object which is persitent to Hibernate but I also want to change the serialization from server to client and i wrote the Custom serialization clases

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationStreamReader;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationStreamWriter;

    public static void serialize(SerializationStreamWriter writer, Object instance) throws SerializationException
    public static void deserialize(SerializationStreamReader reader, Object instance) throws SerializationException
```

I have included the gwt.user in the WEB-INF/lib although i should not, and my jboss server still cries

```
 ERROR: Failed to get SerializationPolicy
```

Have you encourted this problem, does anybody know how to fix it.. preferably without using Gilead ... if there is a simpler solution with Gilead , please show me how... I do not want to access the database object from GWT client, just to use the same object which is defined in shared/ for both client and server but with different serializations..

EDIT:
And care on serialziation about the Collections
[This Guy has in detail](http://dirtbagprogrammer.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/gwt-custom-field-serializers-versus-hibernates-lazyinitializationexception/)

The check is already given...
but I had solved this solution with giving the jboss server explicit the gwt.rpc poilcy to, not only to the apache client...
the damn jboss server could not find those.. so it was mainly configuration problem on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at [HibernateDetachUtility](http://management-platform.blogspot.com/2011/05/detaching-hibernate-objects-to-pass-to.html). The code looks complex but all it does is scan in depth an object graph and nullifies everything that is not serializable by GWT.

I use it in my app and it works nicely (I guess you can meet troubles if you have large graphs of objects to detach). All I added was a package lookup on fieldValue to see if it is of the type of one of my model objects (which are all in the same package) to also detach the value from hibernate. Have a look at the condition on line 505-506-507 (`fieldValue.getClass().getName().contains("org.rhq")` should be replaced by a condition that can match objects of your hibernate model)

To invoke thie utility, just call it like this:

```
// Before returning your response, invoke the next line on your object
HibernateDetachUtility.nullOutUninitializedFields(your_object_here, SerializationType.SERIALIZATION);
// Your object is now safe to be returned to the GWT client
```

Comment: wow it looks complicated.. ill check it ind etail and ill come with question D:

Comment: cann you show me how to use it? just a short how to with a given serializable object?

Comment: So inside the serialize method, i should nullify everythin that is not serializable by gwt.. cool ill test it.. i am not sure if it will work thoug

Comment: public static void serialize(SerializationStreamWriter writer, GameObject instance) throws SerializationException
 { HibernateDetachUtility.nullOutUninitializedFields(instance, SerializationType.SERIALIZATION);
  writer.writeObject(value);
 
  
 }